# Определение настроек глубины цвета всех Мониторов WinApi

Tags: winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, как определить настройки двух мониторов Основного и не основного в Windows с помощью WinApi ? То есть какая глубина цвета (32/24/16 бит) выставлена в данным проверяемый момент.

Функция GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(NULL), BITSPIXEL) - определяет установленную битность Основного экрана, а вот как еще определить неосновного ? Ни как не могу найти.